# Concurrent beforeSave calls allowing duplicates

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

In an effort to prevent certain objects from being created, I set a conditional in that type of object's beforeSave cloud function.

However, when two objects are created simultaneously, the conditional does not work accordingly.

Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Entry", function(request, response) {
    var theContest = request.object.get("contest");
    theContest.fetch().then(function(contest){
      if (contest.get("isFilled") == true) {
          response.error('This contest is full.');
      } else {
          response.success();
    });
});
```

Basically, I don't want an Entry object to be created if a Contest is full. However, if there is 1 spot in the Contest remaining and two entries are saved simultaneously, they both get added.

I know it is an edge-case, but a legitimate concern.

Answer (score 0):

Parse is using Mongodb which is a NoSQL database designed to be very scalable and therefore provides limited synchronisation features. What you really need here is mutual exclusion which is unfortunately not supported on a `Boolean` field. However Parse provides atomicity for counters and array fields which you can use to enforce some control.

See http://blog.parse.com/announcements/new-atomic-operations-for-arrays/
and https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-updating-objects

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using increment and then doing the check in the save callback (instead of fetching the object and checking a Boolean on it).

Looks something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Entry", function(request, response) {
  var theContest = request.object.get("contest");

  theContest.increment("entries");
  theContest.save().then(function(contest) {
    if (contest.get("entries") > contest.get("maxEntries")) {
      response.error('The contest is full.');
    } else {
      response.success();
    }
  });
}
```